# Hugo, how to localized .groupByDate

Tags: date, go, localization, hugo

In my template I sort by months my post like this:

```
{{ range (where site.RegularPages "Type" "in" site.Params.mainSections).GroupByDate "January, 2006" -}}
  <h1>{{ .Key }}</h1> // output: March, 2022
  {{ range (where .Pages ".Params.unlisted" "!=" "true") }}
    <div>{{ time.Format "02 January" .Date }} - {{ .Title }}</div> // output: 01 Mars - This is the title of my post
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

For every post the `time.Format` localized my date in my language (here in French).

But the title witch is group by month is still in English (here it's the `h1`). How can I format my `{{ .Key }}` so it can be localized in my own language and show "Mars, 2022" instead of "March, 2022" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since hugo version [0.97](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/tag/v0.97.0) it works as expected, we don't need some ugly hack to have the text in the corresponding language.

Now you can use `.GroupByDate` and it will use your language settings in your config file.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
{{ time.Format "02 January" .Key }}
```

Or is there something I am missing?

*Update: You can sort by months like this:*

```
{{ range (where site.RegularPages "Type" "in" site.Params.mainSections).GroupByDate "1 2006" -}}
```

*Then you can split your .Key by a space and create a manual lookup for your localized month. Not very pretty, but it gets the job done.*

Comment: No it doesn't work because `.Key` isn't a date, it's a string looking like this: `April, 2022`. So I can't use `time.Format` on it